# How to set default value fields on laravel?

Tags: laravel

In my project, I got many forms, so I've decided to specify each one with an iscription field, for exemple: Kids' form => <input = 'hidden' name = 'inscripted_in' value = 'kids'>. I want to set each one with a default value, but whenever I sign in, I get this error message:
**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'inscripted_at' doesn't have a default value**
Although when I go to Laravel Debug, I still get the inserted constant value, what's the problem?

This is one of my forms

```
                <div class="InputBox">
                    <input type="hidden" name="inscripted_at" value="Adults">
                    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="pending">
                </div>
```

my controller:

```
public function store(Request $req)
   {
    $this->validate($req,[
        'name' => 'required|max:120',
        'surname' => 'required|max:120',
        'job' => 'required|max:120',
        'day' => 'required',
        'month' => 'required',
        'year' => 'required',
        'hobby' => 'required|max:120',
        'help' => 'required|max:120',
        'place' => 'required|max:120',
        'residence' => 'required|max:120',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'scholar_year' => 'required|max:120',
        'tel' => 'required|regex:/(05)[0-9]{8}/',
        ]);

        Chababounauser::create($req->all());

      
       return redirect()->route('chababounausers.index')
                       ->with('success','chababouna User inserted successfully.');
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `fillable` property of the Chababounauser model.

P.S.: Please, don't put spaces in HTML between attribute name and it's value.

Comment: I've cheked it and added the missing fields, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't 'inscripted_at' a  default column in the database giving the date of inscription ? If so, you can't default a value to that kind of output.

Comment: it's not the date, it represents the field of the inscription.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).